# A rails app which gets users location using HTML5 geolocation and saves to data base

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, html, geolocation

Seems pretty simple but I'm struggling.

Here's what I have so far in the view.
I display the location coords just to test its working.
But I also want to persist on Database, hence the ajax call.
Am I doing this the right way or is there an easier or better way?

```
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
    var x=document.getElementById("demo");
    var lat;
    var long;
    function getLocation()
    {
        if (navigator.geolocation)
        {
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);

        }
        else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
    }
    function showPosition(position)
    {
        lat = position.coords.latitude;
        long = position.coords.longitude;
        x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + lat +
                "<br>Longitude: " + long;

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/locations',
            data: { lat: lat, long: long },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'

        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try an "easier" way, use geocoder gem, this provides multiple methods in order to fetch the user location, one of them is by request.

```
request.location.city => Medellin
request.location.country => Colombia
```

You can find useful information in the following links

[Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/273-geocoder?language=es&view=asciicast)

[Official WebPage](http://www.rubygeocoder.com)

[GitHub](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder)

Comment: It is a great gem and very useful - However it is no where near as accurate as HTML5 geolocation.  Its a good fallback though.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758416/storing-html5-geolocation-data). Basically, just set the geolocation via a cookie and read the lat and long from the cookie in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

controller:

```
def location
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json {
        lat = params["lat"]
        lng = params["lng"]
        radius = 5000
        type = "restraunt"
        key = "-"
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=#{lat},#{lng}&radius=#{radius}&types=#{type}&key=#{key}"
        data = JSON.load(open(url))
        render json: { :data => data }
      }
    end
  end
```

routes.rb:

```
get "/location" => "application#location"
```

view:

```
function getLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position){
          $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/location',
            data: { lat: position.coords.latitude, lng: position.coords.longitude },
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(data){
               console.log(data)
            });
        });
    }
  }
```