# Reading a cookie only 1 time at the browser opening

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, cookies, rails-geocoder

I am developing an app that shows some results depending on the "city" that the user is browsing my app. I'll only use this location info for displaying some results, nothing more. I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758416/storing-html5-geolocation-data) and implemented to my app.

I put this code to my _header partial:

```
<%- unless @lat_lng %>
  <script>
    getGeoLocation();
  </script>
<%- end %>
```

this code to application.js:

```
function getGeoLocation() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setGeoCookie);
}

function setGeoCookie(position) {
  var cookie_val = position.coords.latitude + "|" + position.coords.longitude;
  document.cookie = "lat_lng=" + escape(cookie_val);
}
```

and this code to my controller index action:

```
if cookies().key?("lat_lng")
  lat_lng = cookies[:lat_lng].split("|")

  geo_localization = "#{lat_lng[0]},#{lat_lng[1]}"
  query = Geocoder.search(geo_localization).first
  @city = query.state

else
  @city = "nocity"
end
```

But now every time any page loads, I read the cookie again. How can I:

- Look if the cookie exists at the first page loads,
- If exists, read the location
- If it does not, load the page content without location info.
- After the user allowed the location request, create the cookie and find the location, reload the page content with the location data (using ajax or somethng)
- Use the same location until the user closes my app page on the browser, not read the cookie every time a page loads.

By the way I'm not familiar with javascript but trying to handle.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add the information that the cookie has been already interpreted to the cookie itself. Add one more condition to your JavaScript that checks this information thereafter.

Alternatively you could put this information to the QueryString Url and read it from there.

Cheers,